# Html/Javascript - how to get JSON/XML content from window/document (Solr)?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, solr

I got a little problem. I want to open a new window in JavaScript. All fine.
I save the new window in a variable:

```
var testWindow = window.open(url, "_blank");
```

the `url` param is a url to a *Solr server core* - I open a search query in a new window. The response format can be json or xml - no matter what. All I want now is: **Get the response results and save them to a JavaScript array so that I can work with them**. 
The Problem is: the result, for example, in JSON looks like:

```
  {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"test",
      "indent":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

or in XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">test</str>
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="wt">html</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0">
</result>
</response>
```

When I now try the following snippets, I won't get the page contents

```
testWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

or

```
testWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

**what can I do to get the whole page contents and save them into a JS array?**

Comment: Is new window opening necessary? what if you catch response with AJAX?

Comment: I have never worked with Ajax. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the new window is fully loaded. At least that is the common source of problems like yours.

Comment: I now tried for testing:
`testWindow.onload = function() { console.log(testWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML); }` 
I get no output in the console

Comment: But you *do* have something in the new window?

Comment: sure. The source Code of the page contains for example the JSON response of the Solr server

Comment: Yes, that's another problem: JSON is not a DOM tree, you have no `documentElement`, probably not even a `document`. If you do not now the type of the response in advance you need to load it with ajax, check the mime-type with `getResponseHeader('content-type')` and either parse the response text with `JSON.parse()` or `DOMParser()` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can work that out with AJAX, so you send the url in the request and take the response in JSON format and do what you need to do with the data.
[javaScript AJAX Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) or if you like to use jQuery [Jquery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

A example or ajax with jQuery

```
$.ajax ({
type: "post",
url: "search.html",
data:{param1:"value", param2:"value"}
}).done (function (data){
   //work with the data variable is a Json

});
```